# Update multiple computed properties at once using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which has a state like this:

```
this.state = {
  items: {
    itemA: {
      name: "itemA",
      active: false
    },
    itemB: {
      name: "itemB",
      active: false
    },
    itemC: {
      name: "itemC",
      active: false
    }
  }
};
```

And what I'm trying to do is change all the objects inside the `items` object's `active` property to true. I could hardcode a `setState` call for each item, however I think we can do better than that.

My idea is to loop through all the keys of the `items` object, and set the active property of each to true. This is my code so far:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.state.items);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  this.setState({
    tools: {
      ...this.state.items,
      [keys[i]]: {
        ...this.state.items[keys[i]],
        active: true
      }
    }
  });
}
```

But this is only updating the `active` property of the `itemC`, while `itemA` and `itemB` remain false.

**How do you update multiple computed properties at once using `setState`?**

Comment: Your approach is incorrect since you end up having multiple *sources of truth* - there should be only one property active with value pointing to the active element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer, you are mutating the `this.state.items` object before you call `setState`, which is not ideal. Try assigning to a new object. Something like this:

```
const newItems = {};

const keys = Object.keys(this.state.items);

keys.forEach(key => {
    newItems[key] = {
        ...this.state.items[key],
        active: true,
    };
});

this.setState({ items: newItems });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out.

Instead of calling `setState` for each of the `this.state.items` objects, set a variable to `this.state.items`, update the variable, then call `setState` once to set `this.state.items` back to the updated variable. Like so:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.state.items);
let items = this.state.items;
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  items[keys[i]] = {
    ...items[keys[i]],
    active: true
  };
}

this.setState({ items });
```